# Compose initialize class in c++

Tags: c++, initialization, aggregate-initialization

I'm not sure if this is called `compose initialization`.Basically what I want to know is:

- How the objects `foo` in `main` is initialized
- Are there some rules for this kind of initialization because I found it failed sometimes.

Given the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:
  std::string str_mem;
  int int_val = 0;
};

class Bar {
public:
  Bar() = default;
  Bar(int val) : int_val(val) {
  }

  auto GetVal() {
    return int_val;
  }

private:
  int int_val = 0;
};

class Foo : public Base {
public:
  int mem_1;
  int mem_2;
  int mem_3;

  std::string str_mem;
  Bar class_mem;

  auto print() {
    printf("[%d,%d,%d,%s,%d]\n", mem_1, mem_2, mem_3, str_mem.c_str(), class_mem.GetVal());
  }
};

auto main(int argc, char** argv) -> int {
  Foo foo{{"base1", 2}, 1, 2, 3}; // How `foo` is constructed, any constructor get called?
  foo.print();

  Foo foo1{{"base2", 2}, 1, 2, 3, "string", 3};
  foo1.print();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), `Foo` is an [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Explanation).

> Each `direct public base, (since C++17)` array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

Given `Foo foo1{{"base2", 2}, 1, 2, 3, "string", 3};`, the subobject of `Base` is initialized from `{"base2", 2}` (it gets aggregate-initialized too), the data member `mem_1` is initialized from `1`, `mem_2` is initialized from `2`, `mem_3` is initialized from `3`, `str_mem` is initialized from `"string"` (by `std::string`'s constructor taking `const char*`), `class_mem` is initialized from `3` (by the constructor `Bar::Bar(int)`).

Given `Foo foo{{"base1", 2}, 1, 2, 3};`, the preceding members are initialized in the same way as above, except that `str_mem` and `class_mem` are initialized from the empty list, as the result they're default-initialized (by their default constructors).

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members `and bases (since C++17)` or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members `and bases (since C++17)` are `initialized by their default member initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)` copy-initialized from empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates).